# How to get multiple item in a single list in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

[image: Image of list i am retrieving from API]

In this image above I am getting image, video and pdf according to the item i need to display appropriciate widget. Please do assist me.

Comment: Assist you with what? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Would an `if/else` or `switch` statement(s) in the `ListView.builder` function not suffice? In your list item widget, just check the extension of the file/url and create the widget you need.